# How can I upload committed changes to my GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, commit

I used `clone` to create a local copy of my repository on GitHub.

I modified a few files. Then I did:
`git commit -a`

And now I want to save my committed changes to the GitHub repository.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You *push* your changes:

```
git push origin master
```

Replace `master` with the name of the branch you want to push, if different from master.

In case the branch was updated since your last update, the changes may be rejected. In that case you have to *pull* the latest changes on the remote branch first:

```
git pull origin master
```

Optionally, you can rebase your changes on top of the remote master (this will prevent a merge commit), by using:

```
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Comment: Then he can replace master with the name of the branch (updated) :-)

Comment: Here is what I get:

[rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gtihub.com:myreponame' 
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details

What do I need to do?

Comment: @Tobi would one use the local name of the branch or the remote name of the branch?

Answer (score 11):

Follow this steps:

```
1. cd /project path
2. git add *
3. git commit -m "Enter commit message here"
4. git push
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to push your changes to the central repo with `git push`.  It might prompt you for your github password.

Answer (score 2):

To publish your local changes follow the 3 simple steps below:

1. `git add <filename>` or `git add *` to add everything
2. `git commit -m "Enter e message here"`
3. `git push`