# Why is my package.json file not showing on Github after telling me it has been updated?

Tags: git, github, package.json

```
git add .
```

```
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory   
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in package.json. 
PS C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\gg> git push origin main  
Everything up-to-date
PS C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\gg> git pull origin main  
From https://github.com/Osomhe1/sass
 * branch            main       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

but package.json is not showing.

Comment: You need to `git commit` then `git push` to push your changes to the remote server (Github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I upload committed changes to my GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028442/how-can-i-upload-committed-changes-to-my-github-repository)

Comment: From Github docs: [Adding a file to a repository using the command line](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Posted the workflow for your problem, if it solved your purpose do upvote, so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

git commit

then

git push

Then it should be in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the workflow for `pushing(uploading)` local files to github is as follows :-

1. `git add .`  -> this command add all the files to staging area.
2. `git commit -m " your commit message"` -> this is like taking the snapshot of your changes to make it save in commit history.
3. `git push origin master` -> this command pushes the local master branch to origin, origin is the remote URL of the repository in github.

**It's a good practice to run `git status` time to time, this tells which changes needs to be staged or commited.**

Note:- please check whether you have set the upstream which means you have set the origin of remote repository.
to check `git remote -v` -> this will show the URL of your remote repository with fetch and push.

if not then `git remote add URL-of-the-repostiroy`